# How to add like and dislike functionality in my laravel website?

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax, laravel

To be true i am  new to laravel and I am following this tutorial to add like and dislike functionality in my website https://mydnic.be/post/simple-like-system-with-laravel-5 .
here is my migration code:-

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateLikesTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('likes');
}
}
```

here is my user.php code:-

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];


public function likes()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Post', 'likes', 'user_id', 'post_id');
}
}
```

here is my post.php code

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
//
public function likes()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'likes');
}
}
```

here is my web.php code:-

```
<?php


Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();






Route::get('post/{id}/islikedbyme', 'API\PostController@isLikedByMe');
Route::post('post/like', 'API\PostController@like');

?>
```

Here is my PostController.php code:-

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller
{
//

public function isLikedByMe($id)
{
$post = Post::findOrFail($id)->first();
if (Like::whereUserId(Auth::id())->wherePostId($post->id)->exists()){
    return 'true';
}
return 'false';
}

public function like(Post $post)
{
$existing_like = Like::withTrashed()->wherePostId($post->id)-  >whereUserId(Auth::id())->first();

if (is_null($existing_like)) {
    Like::create([
        'post_id' => $post->id,
        'user_id' => Auth::id()
    ]);
} else {
    if (is_null($existing_like->deleted_at)) {
        $existing_like->delete();
    } else {
        $existing_like->restore();
    }
}
}
}
```

here is my layout file code named create.blade.php.Actully like and dislike buttons will be near my comments(btw my commenting system is working perfectly)

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
 <div class="row new-post">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

        <header><h3>Comments</h3></header>
        <form action="/comments" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" name="body" id="new-post" r  rows="5" placeholder="Your review on above game"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post  Comment</button>

        </form>
    </div>
 </div>

 @foreach($comments as $comment) 
 <h1>{{$comment->body }}</h1>
 @endforeach


<div ng-app="Actions">
<span ng-controller="LikeController">
    @if ($post->user->id != Auth::id())
        <button class="btn btn-default like btn-login" ng-click="like()">
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
            <span>@{{ like_btn_text }}</span>
        </button>
    @endif
</span>
</div>
<script>
var app = angular.module("Actions", []);
app.controller("LikeController", function($scope, $http) {

    checkLike();
    $scope.like = function() {
        var post = {
            id: "{{ $post->id }}",
        };
        $http.post('/api/v1/post/like', post).success(function(result) {
            checkLike();
        });
    };
    function checkLike(){
        $http.get('/api/v1/post/{{ $post->id  }}/islikedbyme').success(function(result) {
            if (result == 'true') {
                $scope.like_btn_text = "Delete Like";
            } else {
                $scope.like_btn_text = "Like";
            }
        });
    };
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

The guy who has made this tutorial has also given layout code but it was in angular and ajax which i dont know so I copied it. here is the link to layout code https://gist.github.com/mydnic/278e485b9e636c491ab1 when i am opening link(i.e. http://localhost:8000/comments/create) I am getting error saying this ErrorException in ee0676ab34142915e07250d6b64599d707c58afd.php line 43:
Undefined variable: post. Thanks in advance:-)

Answer (score 1):

The error means you do not pass `$post` variable from `create()` method to the view. You should do something like this in `create()` method:

```
$post = Post::find($id);
return view('comments.create', ['post' => '$post']);
```

Comment: Sir I don't have a create function in PostController.php but I tried replacing isLikedByMe function by create function like this public function create($id)
{
   $post = Post::find($id); but still I was getting the same error
return view('comments.create', ['post' => '$post']);
}

Comment: You're not using conventions anywhere, so it can be called differently. I'm talking about method which is executed when you go to `/comments/create` page.

Comment: Sorry if i am creating a trouble for you but please stick to me.Can be more presize l am not able to figure out what you are saying.

Comment: I am waiting for your answer.If you are busy and can't help then can you please share a link of tutorial for adding like or dislike functionality for beginners like me where it is easy to understand.

Comment: Tutorial you're following is ok to start with (except author uses some bad practices), but since you don't understand some very important basics (like how exactly routes and controllers work), I'd really recommend you to read docs first and only after that continue with more advanced tutorials like you're following now. You'll save yourself a lot of time and nerves if you'll start basics.

Comment: I read the documentation and tried too fix things and ended up getting errors in web.php.Here is my project on github it will be really thankful if you correct thing here https://github.com/Pawan98/laravel (PLEASE HELP ME OUT) waiting for you reply..... :-)

Comment: At least say some thing,Should i wait for your answer?

Comment: @Pawan I've answered in 5th comment. You need to start with basics and use tutorials only after you'll know how Laravel works, what conventions are etc.